# Is it possible to redirect a page in HAML/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, haml

I have this code that create a link to a page to login to facebook at 'auth/facebook'

index.html.haml

```
  - if current_user
    = link_to "Sign out", signout_path, id: "sign_out"
  - else
    = link_to "Sign in with Facebook", "/auth/facebook", id: "sign_in"
```

But if i want if current_user to redirect to '/dashboard' so that when someone is logged in they get redirected from the login page automatically.

sessions controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to dashboard_url
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to login_url
  end
end
```

Comment: Redirections should be done in controllers. Do you have a `SessionController` where you handle the login of a user ?

Comment: yes, I just added it in question. How do I automatically do that when /login is accessed?

Answer (score 1):

In your `SessionsController`, simply check for a session and redirect if it already exists, except for the case when you are attempting to log out:

```
before_filter :except => [:destroy] {|c| c.redirect_to dashboard_path if c.current_user }
```

Comment: see my problem isn't doing that at the moment of login, but I want to do it if the user navigates to the domain.com/login manually. So if they did that and they are logged in, then I want to redirect them automatically. And vice versa for the dashboard

Comment: `/login` should correspond to `SessionsController#new`, which would be covered under this filter. Your corresponding access control filter (something like `before_filter :require_user` or whatnot) should take care of unauthenticated redirection.